# Python - Varrer Arquivo e Extrair Dados de Tags Fixas

Tags: python

Bom dia, galera!

Então, tô iniciando em python e tenho uma dúvida referente a string.

Tenho um arquivo com informações e preciso extrair alguns dados dele e passar para um outro arquivo.
Basicamente, possuo a tag que é referente ao dado, exemplo:

"gatewayTransactionId": "DADOS QUE PRECISO", "amountInCents": DADOS QUE PRECISO.

De quais formas posso fazer isso?

É possível atribuir as tags a uma variável e depois varrer a string após essa tag até o de limitador?
O objetivo é criar um código em que eu possa obter as dados de 1 ou 10 tags.

Obs.:
As tags são sempre estáticas, o que vai mudar é o resultado, sempre.

Conseguem me dar um norte?

Abaixo segue o código que comecei, onde varro o arquivo e procuro pela primeira tag (gatewayTransactionId).

```
in_file = "logfile.txt"
out_file = "file_with_extractedlines.txt"
search_for = "gatewayTransactionId"
str1='string'

line_num = 0
lines_found = 0

with open(out_file, 'w') as out_f:
    with open(in_file, "r") as in_f:
        for line in in_f:
            line_num += 1
            if search_for in line:
                lines_found += 1
                str1=search_for
                print("Os dados foram salvos no arquivo  "file_with_extractedlines.txt")
                print("Found String: {}...".format(str1))
                out_f.write(line)

        print("Found {} lines...".format(lines_found))
```

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que eu percebi, você quer ter um conjunto de `tags` e a partir dessas tags, verificar se em cada linha de um respectivo ficheiro elas existem e então escrever essas linhas noutro ficheiro. Isso pode ser facilmente feito com a função `filter` do Python.

```
fileToRead = "read.txt"
fileToWrite = "write.txt"

lines = open(fileToRead, 'r').split('\n')

tags = ["gatewayTransactionId", "amountInCents"];

parseLines = lambda line: any([tag in line for tag in tags])
dataToWrite = list(filter(parseLines, lines))

writableFile = open(fileToWrite, 'w')
writableFile.write('\n'.join(dataToWrite))
```

Comment: Fala, Pedro!

Então, é quase isso, eu quero identificar as tags e pegar o que é mostrado a partir dela.

Por exemplo:
Linha 1: gatewayTransactionId: exemplo123.

Neste exemplo, eu desejo identificar a tag gatewayTransactionId, salvar a tag e o conteúdo dela em outro arquivo, nesse caso, o exemplo123.

Só que nessa linha dela, não existe apenas essa tag, existem outras, que também preciso extrair os dados da mesma forma que a gatewayTransactionId e salvar no mesmo arquivo.